# I need to add more than one app.root.current in kivy

Tags: kivy, kivy-language, kivymd

I am creating an app in kivy in which basically it gives you a poem once you enter a date and password. For this I have created several windows for each poem. My problem is that i made it so that on_release of the button there is a selective-like structure to show the right poem. The problem is that this only works for the last sentence and not all of them at the same time as supposed to.

```
        Button:
            font_name: "Georgiai"
            font_size: 20
            text: "Enter"
            size_hint: 0.5, 0.5
            background_color: "#00FFCE"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "fifth" if date.text == "01.02.2023" and password.text == "Si" else "fourth"
                app.root.current = "seis" if date.text == "02.02.2023" and password.text == "te" else "fourth"
```

I have tried using multiple on_release: app.root.current but it also does not work. This is the only thing left for it to function so I hope someone can help me. I am quite new in programming

Answer (score 0):

You should move the program logic into Python and not include logic in your kivy file.  Arguments can be passed like this:

```
Button:
    on_release: app.give_poem(_date.text, _password.text, self)
    # or
    # on_release: root.give_poem(_date.text, _password.text, self)
```

I changed your variables by adding an underscore to avoid confusing your variables with other common objects.  I am assuming date and password were ids of other kivy objects.

in your python app or top level widget you can employ your logic.  Here is the basic signature that your method should have within your app or your top level widget object.  This one just prints the arguments sent and you can decide what to do from there.

```
def give_poem(self, _date, _password, my_button):
    print(f"{self}: {_date}: {_password}: {my_button}")
```